# Pull out data from iTunes Connect into Google sheets with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, app-store-connect

Hi everyone and Happy 2018 !

I'm trying to write a Google App Script to pull out data from ItunesConnect.
I tried to use the Node JS module wrapping the Itunesconnect APIto fecth the iTunesConnect API into my Google Sheet starting with this code, but I don't know how to maje the require instruction work

```
function myFunction() {
 var itc = require('itunesconnectanalytics');
 var Itunes = itc.Itunes;
 var AnalyticsQuery = itc.AnalyticsQuery;

 var username = 'LOGIN';
 var password = 'PASS';
 var appId = 'APPID'; //Found in My Apps -> App -> Apple ID or read below on 
  getting the app id. 

var instance = new Itunes(username, password, {
errorCallback: function(e) {
 Logger.Log('Error logging in: ' + e);
},
successCallback: function(d) {
 Logger.Log('Logged in');
}
  });
 }
```

Thanks
J

Comment: Welcome. The question doesn't look like programming question. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to use the Node JS wrapping modules on Google Apps Script.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of ! do yo know if there is another way to pull out data from itunes connect into google sheet ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't.